# Troubleshooting painfully slow Windows XP boot

Tags: windows-xp, boot, troubleshooting

When I reboot my machine, it takes around 10-15 minutes to boot. Tried removing unused programs, disk defragmentation, check disk, but I'm not able to identify the issue.

Any ideas to troubleshoot to see whether there is any failure, trying to start a service/program?

Comment: Can you break down the boot duration? How long between bios post to first xp graphic, how long to first sign of light blue, how long until welcome screen responds to mouse events, how long until desktop appears upon login, how long until start menu responds, how long until disk activity stops...

Answer (score 2):

I'd install [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and see what is configured to run at startup. You can easily manage what you want to run and what you don't want to run. Autoruns has more knowledge of startup locations than any other startup monitor. If you think software is failing to start properly, check the Application event logs in **Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer**.

For removing Silverlight, [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas: 1. In case the computer does not seem to be busy all the time, you might have a program installed that uses resources on a network and can not find / locate them (any more) which leads to the program waiting for the network timeout (2 mins) multiple times. 2. If the computer is busy all the time in this startup, especially the disk, you might have the problem that either one too big program is started or so many programs are started, that they do not fit into main memory. Then windows is "swapping" programs from main memory to the harddisk. Use `msconf` to check the startup configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Try out bootvis to see whats taking long in the boot process: http://majorgeeks.com/BootVis_d664.html

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check for faulty hardware, like a failing hard disk.  Drive Fitness Test from Hitachi can help you with that.

http://www.hitachigst.com/hdd/support/download.htm#DFT

I recommend the CD version.